# Duvida sobre a logica php

Tags: php, html

Fala galera blz? to aqui para pedir uma ajuda pois estou um pouco enrolado, eu estou fazendo um exemplo pra faculdade de perguntas para covid, estou buscando uma forma de pegar as perguntas que foram marcadas no checkbox e fazer a logica com php, só que não estou sabendo como proceder. Eu quero pegar as respostas e colocar uma porcentagem nelas para passar a real chance do usuario ter covid.

a index e a parte do calculo vou mandar agora.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Home - Trabalho Acadêmico</title>

  <!-- Links Site -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://ufersa.edu.br/wp-content/themes/temaufersa/img/favicon.png" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.scss">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Fim Links -->

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Topo -->
  <header>
    <div class="topo">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="sobre.php">Sobre o Projeto</a></li>
          <li><a href="sobre_nos.php">Sobre Nós</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Fim topo -->

  <!-- Slider -->

  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" height="396px" src="https://www.slmandic.edu.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/BANNER-SITE-CORONAVIRUS.png" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" height="396px" src="https://www4.infraero.gov.br/media/802252/banner_santafe_v01.png" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www4.infraero.gov.br/media/802252/banner_santafe_v01.png" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Fim Slider -->

  <!-- Info Covid19 -->
  <section class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">O QUE É CORONAVÍRUS? (COVID-19)</h1>
      <p class="lead text-muted">Coronavírus é uma família de vírus que causa infecções respiratórias, cujos primeiros casos foram isolados pela primeira vez em 1937, porém, apenas em 1965 foi descrito como coronavírus, em decorrência do aspecto apresentado a microscopia, similar a uma coroa.
        O novo agente do coronavírus (SARS-CoV-2) foi descoberto em 31 de dezembro de 2019 após casos registrados na China, e a doença, por determinação da Organização Mundial da Saúde (OMS), foi denominada de COVID19. Em 11 de março de 2020 foi decretada como pandemia pela OMS.</p>
      <p>
        <a href="sobre.php" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Saiba Mais</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Fim Info Covid19 -->

  <!-- Questionario Covid -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Realize o teste do novo <span class="text-muted"> NOVO CORONAVIRUS.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">A sua jornada começa com um questionário de sintomas do novo coronavírus. As respostas são associadas às suas condições prévias de saúde, como doenças cardíacas e respiratórias e geram o resultado da triagem, é só clicar nos sintomas que está sentindo logo abaixo e enviar, logo será dado o resultado.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img src="https://testedocorona.com.br/assets/logo-teste-do-corona.webp" height="120px" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="container">
        <form action="calculo.php" method="post" name="questionario">

        <input id="toggle1" name="pergunta1" value="1" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle1">Teve contato com alguém sintomático nos últimos 30 dias ?</label>

        <input id="toggle2" name="pergunta2" value="2" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle2">Você teve problemas para respirar recentemente (respiração curta) ?</label>

        <input id="toggle3" name="pergunta3" value="3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle3">Seus olhos tem coçado nos últimos dias ?</label>

        <input id="toggle4" name="pergunta4" value="4" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle4">Você está com coriza (nariz escorrendo) ?</label>

        <input id="toggle5" name="pergunta5" value="5" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle5">Teve frebre nos ultimos dias?</label>

        <input id="toggle6" name="pergunta6" value="6" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle6">Tem tossido muito ultimamente ?</label>

        <input id="toggle7" name="pergunta7" value="7" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle7">Você está com dor de garganta?</label>

        <input id="toggle8" name="pergunta8" value="8" type="checkbox">
        <label for="toggle8">Você teve diarréia nos últimos 10 dias?</label>

        <button name="enviar " type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Resultado</button>

  </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Fim Questionario Covid -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <footer>
    <div class="logo_rodape">
      <img src="https://ufersa.edu.br/wp-content/themes/temaufersa/img/favicon.png" alt="">
      <a href="index.php">PROJETO BSI UFERSA - ANGICOS | <?= date('M, Y') ?></a>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>

--------------------------------------------------- calculo.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Home -  Trabalho Acadêmico</title>

      <!-- Links Site -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://ufersa.edu.br/wp-content/themes/temaufersa/img/favicon.png" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.scss">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Fim Links -->

</head>
<body>


<header>
    <div class="topo">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
             <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sobre.php">Sobre o Projeto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sobre_nos.php">Sobre Nós</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</header>


<?php
 
$pergunta1 = $_POST["pergunta1"];
$pergunta2 = $_POST["pergunta2"];
$pergunta3 = $_POST["pergunta3"];

 

$resposta1 = "1";
$resposta2 = "2";
$resposta3 = "3";
$resposta4 = "4";
$resposta5 = "5";
$resposta6 = "6";
$resposta7 = "7";
$resposta8 = "8";

 
$acertou = 0;
$errou = 0;
 
if ($pergunta1 === $resposta1)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 1 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 1 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($pergunta2 == $resposta2)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 2 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 2 errada<br></font>";
}
 
if ($pergunta3 == $resposta3)
{
    $acertou++;
    echo "<font color = blue> Questao 3 correta<br></font>";
}
else
{
    $errou++;
    echo "<font color = red> Questao 3 errada<br></font>";
}
 

 
$calc = 10;
$porcent = $calc * $acertou;
 
echo "<br><br> Voce <font color = blue>acertou</font> $acertou e <font color = red>errou</font> $errou.";
 
 
if ($acertou >=7)
{
echo "<br><br><b><blink>Muito bem, um total de $porcent % de acerto</blink></b>";
}
else
{
echo "<br><br><b><blink> Voce nao foi muito bem, um total de $porcent% de acerto, tente novamente!</blink></b>";
}
 
?>

<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  <?php 
  
    echo "Muito bem um total de $porcent%";
    
  ?>
</div>


<br /><input  type="button" value="voltar" id="botao_voltar" onclick="history.go(-1)">

<footer>
    <div class="logo_rodape">
        <img src="https://ufersa.edu.br/wp-content/themes/temaufersa/img/favicon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <a href="index.php">PROJETO BSI UFERSA - ANGICOS | <?= date('M, Y') ?></a>
</footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

estou dando uma estudada na parte do calculo, estou usando bootstrap para design, se puderem me da uma luz de como proceder agradeço

Comment: Só um detalhe. Quando um checkbox está marcado, ele retorna "on" como value, se não, ele não existe

Comment: muito obrigado.

Comment: Não necessariamente ele retornará 'on', isso depende do método aplicado pelo desenvolvedor.

Comment: @Mike565 Complementando a minha resposta, uma alternativa para a questão do checkbox não retornar nada quando está desmarcado é você trabalhar com banco de dados, é assim que a maioria faz, cria uma tabela, coloca na coluna o valor default "não" e ai se o usuário marcar, você substitui o valor Apenas na pagina de resultado. Cria um if, se não tiver retorno, você considera o valor da tabela, se tiver retorno, você considera como sim, no caso você usaria dois arquivos php, 1 envia os dados via Post e o outro valida e mostra o resultado, é mais limpo assim, use laravel! ficará mais fácil para vc.

Answer (score 1):

Nas palavras da mozila

> **Nota** : Se uma caixa de seleção estiver desmarcada quando seu
> formulário for enviado, não haverá nenhum valor enviado ao servidor
> para representar seu estado desmarcado (por exemplo value=unchecked);
> o valor não é submetido ao servidor.

Não utilize o value para isso, utilize o id do input para identifica-los, lembrando que o nome do input deve ser diferente dos demais.
Primeiro recupere o valor:

```
<input id="toggle1" name="pergunta1" value="<?php echo $resp1 = 1; ?>" type="checkbox" required>
```

Se ele estiver marcado retorna 1, se não estiver marcado não retorna nada, conforme documentação da mozila: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox | neste caso obrigamos o usuário a selecionar o checkbox.

ou seja, no seu caso você vai ter que criar outro chackbox ou, você pode usar javascript para saber se está ou não marcado e converter isso em um valor, mais vamos considerar que esteja marcado, já que o atributo `required` obriga o usuario a marca-lo.

Sabendo disso e considerando que o valor que você deseja está em `$resp1` (`value="<?php echo $resp1 = 1; ?>"`). Faça um if:

```
$resp1 = '1';
$result = ($resp1) ?: '0'; // $result retornará 1 **se**, o valor de $resp1 for igual a 1

$resp1 = '';
echo ($resp1) ?: '0'; // se $resp1 tem valor diferente de '1', ele retorna 0.
```

Com base nisso você pode começar a construir o resto da função de calculo, uma vez que você sabe que 0 é mentira e 1 é verdade.

Está é uma forma antiga de se escrever o if, mais é compatível com as versões anteriores ao php 7.0, caso ocorra um erro, basta retirar as aspas.

Para php 7 e superior:

```
if(1 == $resp1){
  echo "1"; //se resp1 é igual a 1, retorna 1.
} elseif (on == $resp) {
    echo "1"; //se $resp1 é igual a on, retorna 1.
} else {
    echo "0"; //se $resp1 tem valor diferente de 1 e de on, retorna 0.
}
```

Utilize sempre o valor que deseja verificar na frente e coloque dois sinais de igual dessa forma `==`, caso coloque apenas um, ele não irá verificar nada e ainda mudará o valor para o qual você está tentando verificar. (consulte: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um função que pegue todos os inputs, depois percorra ele com um iterador verificando qual está checked, quando checked vc aumenta um no seu contador. Depois você divide o valor do contador pela quantidade de sintomas e multiplica por 100 para ter uma porcentagem de sintomas.
Contador/totalDeInputs*100. Assim da para saber qual a porcentagem de sintomas para ela se preocupar.